# Craue form flow returns false on $flow->isValid() in last step

Tags: php, forms, symfony, craueformflow

I made form wizard with [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) and it works until last step where $flow->isValid() fails and it constantly renders last step instead of going to desired end of form wizard action.

Here is the code necessary to understand where I made mistake:

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Activity $activity)
{
    $currency = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MycompanyUtilBundle:UtilCurrency')->find(1);

    $booking = new Booking();
    $booking->setActivity($activity)
        ->setCurrency($currency)
        ->setReferenceCode(uniqid())
        ->setUserAccount($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MycompanySettingsBundle:UserAccount')->find(1));

    $flow = $this->get('mycompany.form.flow.Booking');
    $flow->bind($booking);

    $form = $flow->createForm();
    if ($flow->isValid($form)) {
        $flow->saveCurrentStepData($form);

        if ($flow->nextStep()) {
            $form = $flow->createForm();
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse(['Status' => 'Form is valid']);
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        '@MycompanyDemoBundle/Default/booking.flow.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'flow' => $flow,
            'activity' => $activity->getTitle(),
            'formData' => $booking,
            'error' => $form->getErrors(true, true),
        ]
    );
}
```

services.yml:

```
mycompany.form.Booking:
    class: mycompany\BookingBundle\Form\BookingType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: mycompany_bookingbundle_booking_form }
mycompany.form.flow.Booking:
    class: mycompany\BookingBundle\Form\BookingFlow
    parent: craue.form.flow
    scope: request
    calls:
        - [ setFormType, [ @mycompany.form.Booking ] ]
```

BookingType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    switch ($options['flow_step']) {
        case 1:
            $builder
                ->add(
                    'activity',
                    'entity',
                    [
                        'class' => 'Mycompany\ActivityBundle\Entity\Activity',
                        'property' => 'title',
                    ]
                )
                ->add(
                    'scheduledDeparture',
                    'entity',
                    [
                        'class' => 'Mycompany\ActivityBundle\Entity\ActivityScheduledDeparture',
                        'property' => 'departureDateTimeString',
                        'empty_value' => 'Select departure time',
                    ]
                )
                ->add(
                    'payer',
                    new CrmContactType()
                );
            break;
        case 2:
            $builder
                ->add(
                    'numberOfAdults',
                    'choice',
                    [
                        'choices' => range(1, 5),
                        'empty_value' => 'Select number of adult travellers'
                    ]
                )
                ->add(
                    'numberOfChildren',
                    'choice',
                    [
                        'choices' => range(1, 5),
                        'empty_value' => 'Select number of child travellers'
                    ]
                );
    }
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        [
            'data_class' => 'Mycompany\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking',
        ]
    );
}
```

BookingFlow:

```
protected function loadStepsConfig()
{
    return
        [
            [
                'label' => 'Select tour',
                'type' => $this->formType,
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Select travellers',
                'type' => $this->formType,
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Confirmation',
            ],
        ];
}
```

and at the end twig file:

```
{% stylesheets '@CraueFormFlowBundle/Resources/assets/css/buttons.css' %}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
<div>
    Steps:
    {% include '@CraueFormFlow/FormFlow/stepList.html.twig' %}
</div>
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ activity }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {% include '@CraueFormFlow/FormFlow/buttons.html.twig' %}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<div>
    Errors:
    {{ dump(error) }}
</div>
<div>
    Form:
    {{ dump(form) }}
</div>
```

There is no extra validation at all, only that field cannot be empty. I get to the last step, and when I click `Finish` button I thought Symfony will generate JSON with "Form is valid" value, but all I got is last step over and over again.
When I debugged that section, clicking on finish gives false to $flow->isValid($form) although every previous step was true and I cannot get to returning JSON response here.

I'm also dumping form and form->getErrors values in twig but nothing resembles that I'm having some error. If I try to persist that data it is successfully persisted.

I didn't find solution for this on git page of bundle. 
Do you guys here maybe know where should I look for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Lines for the solution was this:

app/config/config.yml

```
csrf_protection:
    enabled: true
```

Now when I figured that, it makes sense why it needs csrf_token to work with current workflow given on CraueFormFlowBundle example